# PHP: regex to match complete matching brackets?

Tags: php, regex, nested

In PHP I have the following string:

```
 $text = "test 1
          {blabla:database{test}}
          {blabla:testing}
          {option:first{A}.Value}{blabla}{option:second{B}.Value}
          {option:third{C}.Value}{option:fourth{D}}
          {option:fifth}
          test 2
         ";
```

I need to get all {`option`...} out of this string (5 in total in this string). Some have multiple nested brackets in them, and some don't.   Some are on the same line, some are not.

I already found this regex:

```
(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*\})
```

so the following works fine :

```
preg_match_all('/(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*\})/imsx', $text, $matches);
```

The text that's not inside curly brackets is filtered out, but the matches also include the `blabla`-items, which I don't need.

Is there any way this regex can be changed to only include the `option`-items?

Comment: That sounds like a job for a grammar parser. I had a related problem once. I'm curious if someone will do the job! :)

Comment: how many nested braces can there be?

Comment: [My answer to a different question might be of use to you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11468459/599857)

Comment: I've almost got myself banned for asking similar question. Just had I bad luck with audience it seems. Anyway, I've solved it not by the regex, but by the [stack-based parentheses match](http://www.brilliantsheep.com/stack-based-parentheses-matching-in-java/) loop. Just as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is far better suited to a proper parser, however you can do it with regex if you really want to.

This should work as long as you're not embedding options inside other options.

```
preg_match_all(
    '/{option:((?:(?!{option:).)*)}/',
    $text,
    $matches,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

Quick explanation.

```
{option:               // literal "{option:"
  (                    // begin capturing group
    (?:                // don't capture the next bit
      (?!{option:).    // everything NOT literal "{option:"
    )*                 // zero or more times
  )                    // end capture group
}                      // literal closing brace
```

`var_dump`ed output with your sample input looks like:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "{option:first{A}.Value}"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "first{A}.Value"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(24) "{option:second{B}.Value}"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "second{B}.Value"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "{option:third{C}.Value}"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "third{C}.Value"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "{option:fourth{D}}"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "fourth{D}"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "{option:fifth}"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "fifth"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Leigh, one small problem still exists: if there's a {...} between two options, then the {...} part is included in the match. (see the modified example text)  Any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Dylan it can be done using recursion. See the answer I originally linked in the comments to your question. You should be able to adapt that.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your initial expression to search for the string '(option:)' appended with non-whitespace characters (\S*), bounded by curly braces '{}'.

```
\{(option:)\S*\}
```

Given your input text, the following entries are matched in regexpal:

test 1

{blabla:database{test}}

{blabla:testing}

**{option:first{A}.Value}**  **{option:second{B}.Value}**

**{option:third{C}.Value}**

**{option:fourth{D}}**

**{option:fifth}**

test 2

Comment: Worked ok, but Leigh's answer also works when there is no space between the A and B options, so I picked that one as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression - it was tested using .NET regular expressions, it may work with PHP as well:

```
\{option:.*?{\w}.*?}
```

Please note - I'm assuming that you have only 1 pair of brackets inside, and inside that pair you have only 1 alphanumeric character

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have multiple pairs of brackets on the same level this should works

```
/(\{option:(([^{]*(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?4))*\})[^}]*)|([^{}]+))\})/imsx
```